# Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size of the right side.?

Tags: matlab

```
F=[125 250 500 1000 2000 4000];
T = [1.1 1.0 0.85 0.8 0.65 0.55]
V = 4*5*2.8;
L_n = [76 78 81 84 83 80];
L_f = [80 81 86 87 86 82];
fi = [1];
fi(end+1) = 0.8*(V./T)
```

I want to add the values in to fi however i get the eror "Unable to perform assignment because the indices on the left side are not compatible with the size
of the right side."

Comment: because `size(fi(end+1))` is not the same as `size(0.8*V./T))` you can not put many things in one thing, they don't fit.

Comment: Welcome to the community. Please clarify your question. Which output are you expecting to get? You have already 2 answers both assuming different outputs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Matlab [matrices](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-arrays.html?lang=en) with more than 1 dimesion must have same number of elements for each value in one of the dimensions.

In your case, when `fi` is declared its dimension is `1x1`. And you are trying to add 6 elements on the 2nd position of the first dimension. So, if that worked, you would end up with something like this: `[[1],[a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6]]`. But that is not allowed.

If you still want to do that, you may want to use a [cell array](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/cell-arrays.html?lang=en). Which allows you to add different elements.

Here you have an example:

```
fi = {1}
fi{end+1} = 0.8*(V./T)
```

Notice that some functions like `sum` won't work on a cell array and you would have to do some conversions.

On the other hand if you expected to have a different output like this: `[1 a1 a2 a3 a4 a5 a6]` (like sugested on another answer). You may have different [options](https://es.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/creating-and-concatenating-matrices.html?lang=en) including `horzcat`:

```
fi = horzcat([1],0.8*(V./T))
```

Answer (score 1):

This is my working code

```
F = [125 250 500 1000 2000 4000];
T = [1.1 1.0 0.85 0.8 0.65 0.55];
V = 56;
L_n = [76 78 81 84 83 80];
L_f = [80 81 86 87 86 82];
fi = 0.8 * (V ./ T);
```

and if you want the 1 at the beginning of the array, you can add

```
fi = [1, fi];
```

.